# Why is SHIFT not changing the values?

Tags: cmd

It appears that SHIFT is not working or I do not understand it. Here is the script I am trying to make work.

```
C:>type shiftit.bat
@echo off
echo all is %*
echo 0 is %0
echo 5 is %5
shift /5
echo shifted by 5
echo 0 is %0
echo 1 is %1
echo 2 is %2
```

However, I would have expected that after the shift, %1 would contain "5" or "6". It does not. It appears that the `SHIFT /5` command had no effect. What am I missing?

```
12:57:25.78  C:\src\t
C:>cmd /E:ON
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

12:57:29.57  C:\src\t
C:>shiftit.bat 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
all is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 is shiftit.bat
5 is 5
shifted by 5
0 is shiftit.bat
1 is 1
2 is 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't understand right, 
shift /5 will remove the argument %5, so %6 becomes %5, %7 -> %6 etc.

To remove %1 .. %5 you will have to shift 5 times.
The allargs %* is unaffected by shifting.

See changed batch

```
:: shiftit.bat 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
@echo off
echo all is %*
Echo %%1 IS %1
Echo %%2 IS %2
Echo %%3 IS %3
Echo %%4 IS %4
Echo %%5 IS %5
Echo %%6 IS %6
Echo %%7 IS %7
Echo %%8 IS %8
Echo %%9 IS %9
shift /5
echo shifted by 5

echo all is %*
Echo %%1 IS %1
Echo %%2 IS %2
Echo %%3 IS %3
Echo %%4 IS %4
Echo %%5 IS %5
Echo %%6 IS %6
Echo %%7 IS %7
Echo %%8 IS %8
Echo %%9 IS %9
```

And sample output:

```
> shiftit.bat 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
all is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
%1 IS 1
%2 IS 2
%3 IS 3
%4 IS 4
%5 IS 5
%6 IS 6
%7 IS 7
%8 IS 8
%9 IS 9
shifted by 5
all is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
%1 IS 1
%2 IS 2
%3 IS 3
%4 IS 4
%5 IS 6
%6 IS 7
%7 IS 8
%8 IS 9
%9 IS
```

Comment: That is absolutely right. It is indeed often unexpected that `%*` does not change on using command __SHIFT__ one or more times without or with argument number. __SHIFT__ affects only numbered argument references, i.e. `%1`, `%2`, `%3` without or with a modifier as written by [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings), but not all arguments reference `%*`. That is clearly documented by Microsoft documentation on command [SHIFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shift).